# Cant insert item at start of linked list - python

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I'm currently learning about linked lists for a class and ran into trouble.
I have to be able to insert an item before a specified item so
(Apple,banana,pear)before pear would be (Apple,banana,newItem,pear)
and I managed this with this code:

```
def insert_before(head,data,location):
    current = head
    found = False

    while not found:
        if current.next.data == location:
            new_node = Node(data)
            new_node.next = current.next
            current.next  = new_node
            found = True
        else:
            current = current.next
```

But my issue arose when trying to insert an item before the first item in the list, to try this I thought of doing it as such:

```
if head.data  == location:
    new_node = Node(data)
    head.next = head.next
    new_node.next = head`
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any guides I found on here were to add an item AFTER the first item, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided source code, the use of `head.next = head.next` do nothing and doesn't change the value of the `head` node.

To modify the value of the first node in a linked list by inserting a new node before, it is necessary update the `head` variable.

**Solution 1** - assign the `head` as the returned value of the `insert_before()` function.

> The variable `previous` is used to modify the node before and when is
>   `= None`, the first node must be modified.

```
def insert_before(head,data,location):
    current = head
    previous = None
    found = False

    while not found:
        if (current != None):
            if (current.data == location):
                new_node = Node(data)
                if (previous != None):
                    new_node.next = previous.next
                    previous.next  = new_node
                else:
                    new_node.next = head
                    head = new_node
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.next
        else:
            print('location ',location,' not found.')
            break
    return head
```

The use of the function becomes:

```
myhead = Node(5)
print(myhead.data) #  >> 5
myhead = insert_before(myhead,3,5)
print(myhead.data) #  >> 3
print(myhead.next.data) #  >> 5
```

**Solution 2** - use the OOP of Python by adding a `head`attribute in the `Node` class.

> The OOP approach is quite similar, but instead of storing the `head`
>   node outside the function, the function `insert_before()` is added to
>   the class `Node`.

**Step 1** - add in the class `Node` the attribute `head`.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node
        self.head = self # store the first node
```

**Step 2** - use the internal `self.head` instead of the `head` as parameter

> In that case, when the new node shall be inserted before the first
>   node, the assignment is very simple `self.head = new_node`.

```
def Insert_Before(self,data,location):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    print('insert ',data,' before ',location)

    while not found:
        if (current != None):
            if (current.data == location):
                new_node = Node(data)
                if (previous != None):
                    new_node.next = previous.next
                    previous.next  = new_node
                else:
                    new_node.next = self.head
                    self.head = new_node # update the first node
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.next
        else:
            print('location ',location,' not found.')
            break
    return
```

The use of the function becomes:

```
myhead = Node(5)
print(myhead.data)
myhead.insert_before(3,5)
print(myhead.head.data)
print(myhead.head.next.data)
```

> Warning: instead of using `myhead` as the first node, use the
>   `myhead.head` attribute.